# Unreserved names

Tags: c, naming-conventions, naming

The C language has a set of outright reserved keywords. However, there is a much larger set of identifiers that are reserved or semi-reserved, whose use is at least strongly not recommended because they are used by the standard library or various system headers, or may be so used in future, etc; there is a comprehensive though not exhaustive list of those here: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html

The set of such names is much too large to be feasible to enumerate.

Looking at it from the perspective of using C as a compilation target, I'm looking for the reverse: a set of names I can generate, that are guaranteed to be *not* reserved, to be free for application use.

Clearly this requirement could be effectively met as far as it goes by prepending a UUID to every name, but there is an additional requirement that the generated code be as amenable as possible to eyeball debugging, so the namespace should be as simple as possible, e.g. if all names are to have a common prefix, that prefix should be as short as possible.

What's the simplest way to characterize a set of names that are guaranteed, or failing that highly likely, to be free for application use? For example, would it be safe to use arbitrary names prefixed with `x_` or suchlike?

Comment: I've never met this as a serious problem.  I use app-specific names if possible and prefix them by class, eg 'tvSearchFolders' is a treeview of the directory tree that the app will search. Empirically, I rarely suffer from name clashes.  If you are getting that a lot, maybe you should move to C++ or some other language that has namespaces/modules:)

Comment: @MartinJames Using C++ as a compilation target is not out of the question, but would only make sense if it were going to provide other benefits apart from this. Namespaces won't help in the case of clashes with macros defined in system or library header files.

Comment: The C library does a fairly good job avoiding naming conflicts by using common prefixes, e.g. `f` for the file functions `fopen`, `fread`, `fgets`, `fclose`. And `str` for the string functions, and `mem` for `memcpy`, `memmove`, `memset`, `memcmp`. There are of course plenty of exceptions, e.g. the functions in `<math.h>`. So what's the best approach? Use your own common prefix and hope for the best. There's no absolute answer that's guaranteed to work, because as soon as you find and adopt the perfect naming convention, everyone else will too, and you'll be right back where you started.

Comment: We look at words from left to right, so putting prefixes in your names kills the "eyeball debugable". If you have a function called `x1x2x3_printf`, you have to get through the `x1x2x3_` part (left->right). However, if you have `printf_x1x2x3`, then you spot which function it is right away. Since you'll generate that, and since you can append something like `__666`, I think you could come up with a pretty hard-to-collide function name with a small suffix.

Comment: Steve Clamage has said this is the reason C++ added the `std::` namespace, breaking “hello, world!” Otherwise, it would have been impossible to write a compliant program, as there would have been no way to predict what identifiers might be added to the headers in the future.

Comment: However, the C standards committee has been very cautious about adding new keywords or identifiers to existing header files. When they have needed to add a new keyword, it always starts with an underscore, and you need to `#include` a new header file in order ti alias it to anything that might break existing code.

Comment: Most OSes also allow you to define feature-selection macros, which future versions of the library should check before enabling any new features that might break legacy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most C libraries provide feature-selection macros, which allow you to specify which version of the interface you are using.  If you set `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` and `_XOPEN_SOURCE` before including any system headers on Linux or UNIX, your system libraries will not declare any identifiers that future versions of UNIX might define.  (In theory, setting either one by itself should suffice, but it’s good defensive coding to set both, as this will prevent one or the other from being set inconsistently by someone else.)  [On Windows,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers?redirectedfrom=MSDN) you would declare `NTDDI_VERSION` and `_WIN32_WINNT`.

The C Standard Library  only provides feature-*test* macros, not macros that let you choose an interface, but compliers support a flag such as `-std=c20`, and you should set this in your build scripts.  This should disable any new keywords or identifiers that get added to the language in the future.

If you depend on a specific version of a library, and are worried that changes to its header files could break your code, you can put a copy of the headers (and to be absolutely certain, the library itself) in your project tree.  If the library is open-source, making a note of which version you used should let anyone else download the right version.  Otherwise, you’re at the mercy of its maintainers.

Do **not** declare `_BSD_SOURCE` or `_GNU_SOURCE` if this is a concern for you!  Linux headers without glibc bindings, such as `<linux/module.h>`, generally don’t have this kind of versioning.

Some languages have much more robust solutions for this, such as `cabal` and `stack` for Haskell or `cargo` for Rust.